# How do I refer to widget.function() in the build method of a stateless widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am trying to make the build method in my _StatefulBoyState class cleaner. Currently, the build method contains the following:

```
class _StatefulBoyState extends State<StatefulBoy> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text(widget.title),
        onPressed: widget.doSomething,
      )
        );
  }
}
```

Where doSomething() and [title] are a function and a String, respectively, both defined within the StatefulBoy class.

But because I'm going to be using this exact button implementation in other stateful widgets, I would like to make the button its own separate class, like so:

```
class _StatefulBoyState extends State<StatefulBoy> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FunctionButton(),
        );
  }
}




class FunctionButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: Text(widget.title)
      onPressed: () {
        widget.doSomething;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

The problem, as you've probably already noticed, is that widget.doSomething is undefined within the body of FunctionButton. Should I make FunctionButton() a subclass of StatefulBoy or something? That would kind of defeat the purpose of being able to use this class in other stateful widgets. Maybe what I'm trying to do here is not advisable. If someone could send me to some Flutter documentation on this topic I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make FunctionButton a Stateful widget and pass title and doSomething to it. You can check the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive#the-parent-widget-manages-the-widgets-state).

```
class _StatefulBoyState extends State<StatefulBoy> {

  doSomething() {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FunctionButton(
        title: title,
        function: doSomething()           
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FunctionButton extends StatefulWidget {

  final String title;
  final Function function;

  FunctionButton({Key key, this.title, this.function}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FunctionButtonState createState() => _FunctionButtonState();
}

class _FunctionButtonState extends State<FunctionButtonPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: Text(widget.title)
      onPressed: () {
        widget.function;
      }
    );
  }
}
```